# VBA code for deleting

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to write inside a button in a userform to clear the cell if it is less than 1%

```
Range("G9:G28").Select
Selection.ClearContents if range("g9:g28) < 0
```

This is probably very wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dim c as range

for each c in activesheet.range("G9:G28")
  if c.value < 0 then c.clearcontents
next
```

Comment: Maybe `if c.value2 < 0.01 then c.clearcontents` ...? I'm not sure if the narrative or the code in the OP is correct.